# Angular 6 directive is not initialized when placed in lazy loaded module's component

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

Very new to Angular 6.

I have declared a directive in AppModule and in the appComponent template if I apply that directive it works, In the app component there is a router outlet in which a lazy loaded module gets loaded at very beginning.

Now if I want to apply the directive in any component template of the lazyloaded module, the directive is not being initialized. The directive is an attribute directive and I have declared it properly and used too because inside app component it's working fine.

Not getting any clue, please help.

Comment: A directive must be declared, or imported in order to be used by a module. Since it's declared in AppModule, it's only available in that module. You need to declare it and export it in a shared module, and import that shared module in all modules that need to use that directive. https://angular.io/guide/sharing-ngmodules

Comment: You have to export your directive from the module to be used by external components.Add this to your module file where you have declared it  `exports : [MyDirective]`

Comment: OK, now the issue is I have declared this at AppModule and export too. I thought if anything declared in app module should be available to all modules. As I have declared it in AppModule so not declared in any shared module and so did not import anything extra.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I see there is an issue with your design. Instead of having your `directive` in the `AppModule`, create a  `SharedModule` and then implement the `directive` in there. Import `SharedModule` everywhere else in your app. This way you can access your `directive` from external components (from other modules).

Make sure you declare and export it inside `SharedModule`

> I thought if anything declared in app module should be available to
>   all modules

No this is not correct, Child modules does not know what  you have inside the `AppModule`. `ChildModule`'s are just another independent modules like `AppModule`. You could have simply exposed `AppModule` to `ChildModule`, but that might cause the circular dependency. That is the reason you have to make use of `SharedModule`

Answer (score 0):

If we create directives in the feature module/shared module make sure that we need to have them put in the declaration section and export section. import this feature/shared module where it is used.